# how to redirect result "!find ..." command to put lftp command

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, lftp

I'd like to put files from result of !find command from lftp.

I tried:

```
$> lftp -u foo, sftp://bar
lftp foo@bar$> put < !find ./local -type f
```

But failed!!

This worked:

```
$> lftp -u foo, sftp://bar
lftp foo@bar$> !find ./local -type f | awk '{print "put "$1}' > /tmp/files.lftp
lftp foo@bar$> source /tmp/files.lftp
```

Is there another way!? I'd like to use stdio redirects (pipes, stdin...).

Comment: `mput` is the typical way to request 'multiple' files on ftp (instead of just `put`). I haven't heard of `lftp` and I'll be surprised if `mput < !find ...`  works, but if it does please post back so that we know. The `source` method looks pretty darn good. why spend time trying to fix something that is working? life it too short ;-) Good luck.

Comment: i agree with you! The `mput< !find ...` don't worked too.
Let me explain what i need. I need to upload files (only files) from:

`/local/foo/06012012
/local/foo/06022012
/local/foo/06032012
...
/local/foo/07012012
/local/foo/07022012
/local/foo/07032012
...
/local/foo/08012012
/local/foo/08022012
/local/foo/08032012
...`

to:

`/remote/foo/062012
/remote/foo/072012
/remote/foo/082012`

`lftp` provide `mirror -R` command to upload recursively, but the entire paths are uploaded too. I only need to upload data files to another paths.

Comment: I don't think I"ll be able to help with that as I don't know anything about lftp. Is that l=linux? It might help to add a tag to your question to indicate your OS. AND, you should edit your question to include the info in the comment above, formatted to be useful for other readers ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I have read through the whole [man lftp(1)](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) and it seems that **the way you have chosen is actually the best one**.

1. `!` command doesn't support direct combination with another commands, as you tried `put < !find ...`
2. The only way to upload files is using `put`, `mput` or `mirror`. `mirror` is of no use for you as you noted, because it preserves the path.
3. `put` or `mput` commands don't support any means to specify a file with list of files to upload.

So, the only possibility is what you have: generate the script and use `source` to run it.

What you could try is to put all the files into one `mput` command:

```
!find ./local -type f | awk -v ORS=" " 'BEGIN{print "mput "}{print}' > /tmp/files.lftp
```

but be careful: although I haven't found it in the docs, there might be limitation for maximum line size! So I think in the end your way is the best way to go.

Note that you can also code-golf your command to:

```
!find ./local -type f -printf "put %p\n" > /tmp/files.lftp
```

Comment: The `mput` solution you gave is pretty much what I tried yesterday. Regarding the limitation, I tried with > 2000 filenames, and it worked. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
source -e find ./local -type f \| sed \'s/^\(.*\)$/put \"\1\"/\'
```

The `sed` command surrounds each output line of `find` with double-quotes (`"`) and prepends a `put`. This will work for filenames containing spaces and some other critical characters, but will fail for filenames containing double-quotes, line-breaks, ... You may extend the substituition performed by `sed` accordingliy, if you happen to have such characters in your filenames.

Note that the backslash (`\`) in front of the pipe sign (`|`), the double- and single-quotes are needed to escape interpretation by the `lsftp` command line parser. To test the command on a `sh`-like shell, use:

```
find ./local -type f | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/put "\1"/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum depth of the `local` directory, you can use plain `mput` command like this:

```
lcd local && mput * */* */*/* */*/*/*
```